# Patch data fetched from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, json-server

I'm a beginner and trying to create a practice project. I'm trying to "patch" a data fetched from an API.
My json file looks like this:

```
{
  "classes": [
    {
      "title": "Office Syndrome",
      "length": "60 Minutes",
      "instructor": "A. W.",
      "difficulty": "Intermediate",
      "description": "Suitable for people who are always constantly inactive working in front of computers.",
      "availableSpot": "10",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Digestive Flow",
      "length": "60 Minutes",
      "instructor": "MJ",
      "difficulty": "Beginners",
      "description": "Good for digestion",
      "availableSpot": "8",
      "id": 2
    }
]
```

I'm trying to create a functionality where the class is bookable where the availableSpot will be decreased by 1 after each booking.

My handleBook function currently looks like this:

```
const handleBook = (index) => {
    setSelectedYogaClass(true);

    if (selectedYogaClass === index) {
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/classes", {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ availableSpot: data.availableSpot - 1 }),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error("Sorry, something went wrong");
          }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setBookingError(err);
        });
    }
    console.log(selectedYogaClass);
    setModalIsOpen(false);
  };
```

And this is how I am calling the function

```
 <button
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => handleBook(index)}
                    className="button button--outline"
                  >
                    Yes
                  </button>
```

However, I am getting a 404 error and am wondering what the problem is?
Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: your url should be like this `fetch('/classes', ...)`

Comment: @miraj the URL looks fine, also that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Do you have a server-side or mock server? What is the service running on localhost:8000?

Comment: @slideshowp2 this is a mock server

Comment: What mock server do you use? Show the code or the command. Need more detail to locate the error.

Comment: The json file is in my local host and I ran this command  "start": "json-server -p 8000 -w db.json". Is this what you mean? @slideshowp2

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify specific resource when you use [plural routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#plural-routes) like `http://localhost:8000/classes/:id`.

If you want to update(`PATCH`) the `availableSpot` field of `class` with id `1`, you should use `http://localhost:8000/classes/1`

An working [example](https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/67316808)

Comment: To update(PATCH) more dynamically, i gave `id` as a parameter and passed the url like this:   "http://localhost:8000/classes/" + id  thanks for pointing me out at the right direction @slideshowp2